# How does Qt control the camera on the mac?

Tags: macos, qt

As on Windows it is useless to write, you can't get the camera screen at all.

What should I do?

Do I need to apply for permission?

Where should I put the file Info.plist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Info.plist you should include:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME} ...a description of why the camera is used by your app...</string>
```

Here is an example of displaying the camera input.
**mainwindow.h:**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QCamera>
#include <QCameraInfo>
#include <QCameraViewfinder>
#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QCamera *m_camera;
    QList<QCameraInfo> m_cameras;
    QCameraViewfinder *m_cameraViewFinder;

private:
    bool checkCameraAvailability();

private slots:
    void setCamera(const QCameraInfo &cameraInfo);
    void on_camerSelectBox_currentTextChanged(const QString &arg1);
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp:**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
      m_cameraViewFinder(new QCameraViewfinder)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Detect Cameras
    m_cameras = QCameraInfo::availableCameras();
    for (const QCameraInfo &cameraInfo : m_cameras) {
        ui->camerSelectBox->addItem(cameraInfo.description());
    }

    // Make sure there is at least one camera available, and start with the default camera as preview.
    if(checkCameraAvailability()) {
        setCamera(QCameraInfo::defaultCamera());
    }
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete m_cameraViewFinder;
    delete m_camera;
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::setCamera(const QCameraInfo &cameraInfo)
{
    m_camera = new QCamera(cameraInfo);

    m_camera->setViewfinder(m_cameraViewFinder);
    ui->previewLayout->addWidget(m_cameraViewFinder);

    m_camera->start();
}

bool MainWindow::checkCameraAvailability()
{
    if (QCameraInfo::availableCameras().count() > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void MainWindow::on_camerSelectBox_currentTextChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    if(checkCameraAvailability()) {
        for (const QCameraInfo &cameraInfo : m_cameras) {
            if( cameraInfo.description() == arg1 ) {
                setCamera(cameraInfo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In you **mainwindow.ui** you should include:

- A layout named `previewLayout`
- A QComboBox named `camerSelectBox`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it helped me a lot!